# How to comparing the TPS of ReentrantLock and Synchronization

Tags: java, synchronization, reentrantlock

I want to measure the TPS of ReentrantLock and Synchronization.At The same Time I want draw a chart to show the change as the count of thread goes on.

But Now,I can not find a satisfied tools to complete it.The result is like this picture:
[The Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HhWc7.jpg)

Is there any tools or example that can help me achieve it?

Thank you!
I have write some code,But I am not good at collecting data elegantly.

```
private ReentrantLock lock = new ReentrantLock();

public synchronized void testSynchronized() {
    sleepRandomTime();
}

public void testReentrantLock() {
    lock.lock();
    try {
        sleepRandomTime();
    } finally {
        lock.unlock();
    }
}

private void sleepRandomTime() {
    long sleepTime = (int) (Math.random() * 100);
    try {
        Thread.sleep(sleepTime);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}

public class ThreadTest1 extends Thread {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        testSynchronized();
    }
}

public class ThreadTest2 extends Thread {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        testReentrantLock();
    }
}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? For the start, you could write a program which will perform the work you are trying to measure and then display the result. Drawing a chart deserves its own question.

Comment: now,I have add some code.As yet  I can not find a effective way to collec data for showing the TPS.Thank you

Answer (score 0):

For micro benchmarking I use JMH.  Try it.  Btw a read - write lock is orders of magnitude faster than synchronised block in cases of contention, especially if you have read operations over lapping with write operations.

Comment: I have tried JMH. um,It is a effective way.Thank you